# how to change field names in preview page (/admin/user/{id}/show)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-backpack

I just installed Laravel Backpack Pro and added an isAdmin column to my Users column / model.

I've updated app/Http/Controllers/Admin/UserCrudController.php so that when editing a user and viewing the list of all users isAdmin shows up as Admin but how do I do that in the user preview page (`/admin/user/{id}/show`)?

For `/admin/user/{id}/edit` I modified `setupUpdateOperation()` to include this:

```
CRUD::field([
    'name' => 'isAdmin',
    'label' => 'Admin',
]);
```

For `/admin/user` I modified `setupListOperation()` to include this:

```
CRUD::column('isAdmin')->label('Admin');
```

But idk what function I'd need to modify to make the user preview page's behavior change. Initially I thought that `setupListOperation()` might do that page as well but, after modifying it, it turns out that that's not the case.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use ShowOperation trait in your UserCrudController

`use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\ShowOperation;`

then you can override the `setupShowOperation()` method the same as you did in `setupListOperation()` and `setupUpdateOperation()`